# import file from folder using selenium for python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

After downloading a file from a webpage using Selenium for Python, I want to upload that file to another page. I've been using the suggested solutions I've found so far, but I keep having the element not visible.

Here is the code :

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('id_in_page')
driver.execute_script("$(arguments[0]).click();", element)
element.send_keys('path_to_folder/file_to_upload')
```

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element.

I tried to click on element, as I've notice page has a td class="hide" which I think might be causing the issue. Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you update the question with the relevant ***HTML***? Possibly share the URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
...
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'id_in_page')))
element = driver.find_element_by_id('id_in_page')

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element)
actions.click()
actions.send_keys('path_to_folder/file_to_upload')
actions.perform()
...
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. Sorry I forgot to mention I had already tried using ActionChains but still nothing. It seems I need to select the file from my machine as the send_keys seems ineffective